# What is the best looking web standards treeview for the web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

Does anyone know of a good TreeView for the web that is nice looking, efficient, and uses web standards? We use jQuery so it would be nice if it did too, but that isn't a requirment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problems with this one

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Comment: I was hoping for something with more eye candy, but maybe there isn't anything like I'm thinking for the web.

Comment: You can use custom animations with that plugin. Im not really sure what you mean by eyecandy though. Something like this wouldn't really benefit from lots of images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out DynaTree? It is based on jQuery, allows lazy loading of subtree data, AJAX/JSON data binding, drag & drop, selectable items (checkboxes) etc.

Here is the link:
http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/

Another one which looks quite good is jsTree. It is also higly configurable and allows AJAX callbacks with data binding, checkboxes to select items etc.

You can find it here:
http://www.jstree.com/

Both are free to use.